# Output pulse on rising edge

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm new to electronics and I have a problem with timers and pulses.

I have a 24 V input signal that turns on every now and then. On every rising edge of this signal (from 0 to 24 V), I want to output a 24 V signal for 100 ms. (No retrigger.)

I've been looking into LTC6993-1 and 555 timers, however, to my understanding both of these require a constant power source to operate (which I want to avoid) and they also seem rather complex compared to the problem.

I wonder if there is an easier approach to accomplishing this without having a constant power source and just using the 24 V input signal?

Comment: What's providing the 24 V signal and what is it feeding? What is the tolerance on the timing? Is it industrial or vehicle?

Comment: The input signal is coming from a control unit and is feeding an LED lamp on a vehicle. The output tolerance has to be between 95ms and 105ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1 (a) Simple. (b) Still simple.*

Figure 1a might work. It relies on the relay being a little slow to energise. Meanwhile you get an output pulse until RLY1 picks up.

If that's too quick then replace RLY2 with a 12 V relay, add in R1 with a value equal to the coil's resistance and add in some capacitance to cause a pick-up delay. The time constant will be approximately $ \frac {R_1 C} 2 $ farads.

If you want more precise timing then you'll have to go electronic. 24 V is standard industrial control voltage and you'll find many, many timers available for that.